# When i start the intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE it automatically opens empty recent folder?

Tags: java, android, storage-access-framework

What i'm trying to achieve is to delete a file on the sd card, i tried the file.delete method which didn't work because sd cards are read only now.

So i read a post about SAF (Storage Access Framework) to gain sd card write access by storing the treeUri we get in onActivityResult.

File deleting works fine now, but when i start the intent **Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE** sometimes it returns the recent folder which is empty and the way to show the files on the sdcard is to click on the overflow icon and then select show SDCARD or Internal Storage which may confuse some people when they run my app.

i tried adding these to my intent:      **intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);**
        **intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);**
        **intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);**

which works on some devices, but it's a private API and on some it doesn't work.

So is there a way to like automatically open a specific directory or show a hint dialog with steps explaining which directory they should chose?

```
private void getSDCardAccess(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
} 


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_EXTERNAL_ACCESS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri treeUri = null;

        if (data != null){
            treeUri = data.getData();
        }

        if (treeUri != null && getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            StorageUtil storageUtil = new StorageUtil(getActivity());
            //Takes the access so that we can use it again after the app reopens
            storageUtil.storeTreeUri(treeUri.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "treeUri: " + treeUri.toString());
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG,"uri is empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to like automatically open a specific directory

If you have a `Uri` to it that you got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` previously, you should be able to supply that via `DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`. Per [the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE):

> Callers can set a document URI through `DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` to indicate the initial location of documents navigator. System will do its best to launch the navigator in the specified document if it's a folder, or the folder that contains the specified document if not.

---

> or show a hint dialog with steps explaining which directory they should chose?

You would need to do that yourself, prior to calling `startActivityForResult()` for the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i did some research and DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI is what i need, but i forgot to mention i'm using api 21 - 28 so it wont work on devices below api 26, any alternative for those devices?

Comment: @GamericiousBlog: Ah, sorry, I forgot that `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` is newer. There is no documented solution for older devices, and I am not aware of any undocumented options (other than the ones in your question).

Comment: So only solution i could use is to show a dialog with steps explaining how to choose a directory, but how do i show a dialog inside the documentsprovider? I tried creating a dialog inside my method where i start the intent  ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE before calling startActivityForResult() but it isn't showing the dialog?

Comment: @GamericiousBlog: "but how do i show a dialog inside the documentsprovider?" -- you don't. You show a dialog in your activity, and after the user clicks OK (or whatever), then you do your `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` work. "I tried creating a dialog inside my method where i start the intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE before calling startActivityForResult() but it isn't showing the dialog? " -- creating a `DialogFragment` usually requires more work than that. If you find that you need help with dialogs, and can't find existing answers, ask a fresh SO question with a [mcve].